# Fail to save the attribute in NSManagedObject in my Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 3 attribute in my setting entity.  It is dayOfExpiredDay, dayOfExpiredDay1 and timeOfExpiredDay.  After running the below code, it can only save timeOfExpiredDay value.  The strange thing is that it save the value into dayOfExpiredDay1 but dayOfExpiredDay is Nil.  I print out the mySettingItem data information on below as well.  Does anyone can help it?  Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.maximumValue = 99
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
    mySettingList = contxt.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!

    if mySettingList.count == 0 {
        daysBeforeExpiredDate = 0
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Setting", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
        var newItem = Setting(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
        newItem.dayOfExpiredDay = daysBeforeExpiredDate
        println("newItem.dayOfExpiredDay:\(newItem.dayOfExpiredDay)")
        let initialDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        initialDateComponents.year = 2014
        initialDateComponents.month = 12
        initialDateComponents.day = 25
        initialDateComponents.hour = 7
        initialDateComponents.minute = 0
        initialDateComponents.second = 0

        let initialDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(initialDateComponents)!


        /***** NSDateFormatter Part *****/

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

        notificationTime = initialDate
        newItem.timeOfExpiredDay = notificationTime

        contxt.save(nil)
        let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
        mySettingList = contxt.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
        mySettingItem = mySettingList[0] as! NSManagedObject
    } else {
        mySettingItem = mySettingList[0] as! NSManagedObject
        daysBeforeExpiredDate = mySettingItem.valueForKeyPath("dayOfExpiredDay") as! Int
        var num : Double = Double(daysBeforeExpiredDate)
        stepper.value = num
        notificationTime =  mySettingItem.valueForKeyPath("timeOfExpiredDay") as! NSDate
    }
    println("mySettingItem:\(mySettingItem.description)")

    updateDatePicker(notificationTime)
    updateLabelNotification(daysBeforeExpiredDate)
}
```

***Here is the Setting.swift***

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Setting)
class Setting: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dayOfExpiredDay: Int
    @NSManaged var dayOfExpiredDay1: Int
    @NSManaged var timeOfExpiredDay: NSDate
}
```

I have enabled the SQL debug mode -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3 and here is the output.

***The first run the app and set the below output.***

```
2015-05-15 20:05:35.244 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE8973DD-5E27-4AA9-8976-    1CBB39ED4F32/data/Containers/Data/Application/55364660-BDEC-43E0-A3A5-191B0E53D490/Documents/JPList.sqlite"
2015-05-15 20:05:35.245 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: creating schema.
2015-05-15 20:05:35.245 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma page_size=4096
2015-05-15 20:05:35.245 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma auto_vacuum=2
2015-05-15 20:05:35.249 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2015-05-15 20:05:35.249 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
2015-05-15 20:05:35.249 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZLIST ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZEXPIREDON TIMESTAMP, ZFIRSTALARMON TIMESTAMP, ZQUANTITY FLOAT, ZINFO VARCHAR, ZITEM VARCHAR, ZQUANTITY1 VARCHAR, ZPHOTO BLOB ) 
2015-05-15 20:05:35.250 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE ZSETTING ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY INTEGER, ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1 INTEGER, ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY TIMESTAMP ) 
2015-05-15 20:05:35.250 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: Creating primary key table.
2015-05-15 20:05:35.250 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_PRIMARYKEY (Z_ENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_NAME VARCHAR, Z_SUPER INTEGER, Z_MAX INTEGER)
2015-05-15 20:05:35.256 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(1, 'List', 0, 0)
2015-05-15 20:05:35.257 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_PRIMARYKEY(Z_ENT, Z_NAME, Z_SUPER, Z_MAX) VALUES(2, 'Setting', 0, 0)
2015-05-15 20:05:35.257 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: CREATE TABLE Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_UUID VARCHAR(255), Z_PLIST BLOB)
2015-05-15 20:05:35.258 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
2015-05-15 20:05:35.258 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM Z_METADATA WHERE Z_VERSION = ?
2015-05-15 20:05:35.258 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 1
2015-05-15 20:05:35.258 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
2015-05-15 20:05:35.258 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 1
2015-05-15 20:05:35.259 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = "26333CDC-2708-470E-A0DE-F579A2BBCAC7"
2015-05-15 20:05:35.259 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = <NSData len=355>
2015-05-15 20:05:35.259 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: Saving new meta data; version = 1 ; UUID = 26333CDC-2708-470E-A0DE-F579A2BBCAC7
2015-05-15 20:05:35.259 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2015-05-15 20:05:35.262 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
2015-05-15 20:05:35.266 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
2015-05-15 20:05:35.266 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200
2015-05-15 20:05:35.266 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
2015-05-15 20:05:35.270 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZEXPIREDON, t0.ZFIRSTALARMON, t0.ZINFO, t0.ZITEM, t0.ZPHOTO, t0.ZQUANTITY, t0.ZQUANTITY1 FROM ZLIST t0 
2015-05-15 20:05:35.270 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
2015-05-15 20:05:35.270 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x786c4a40> on entity 'List' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZEXPIREDON, t0.ZFIRSTALARMON, t0.ZINFO, t0.ZITEM, t0.ZPHOTO, t0.ZQUANTITY, t0.ZQUANTITY1 FROM ZLIST t0 ' returned 0 rows with values: ()
2015-05-15 20:05:35.270 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 0 rows.
2015-05-15 20:05:38.164 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 
2015-05-15 20:05:38.165 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
2015-05-15 20:05:38.165 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x78782170> on entity 'Setting' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 ' returned 0 rows with values: ()
2015-05-15 20:05:38.165 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0006s for 0 rows.
newItem.dayOfExpiredDay:0
2015-05-15 20:05:38.175 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2015-05-15 20:05:38.175 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?
2015-05-15 20:05:38.176 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: getting max pk for entityID = 2
2015-05-15 20:05:38.176 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET Z_MAX = ? WHERE Z_ENT = ? AND Z_MAX = ?
2015-05-15 20:05:38.176 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: updating max pk for entityID = 2 with old = 0 and new = 1
2015-05-15 20:05:38.176 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2015-05-15 20:05:38.179 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2015-05-15 20:05:38.180 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSETTING(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-05-15 20:05:38.180 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)1
2015-05-15 20:05:38.180 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)2
2015-05-15 20:05:38.181 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
2015-05-15 20:05:38.181 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = nil
2015-05-15 20:05:38.181 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[4] = 0
2015-05-15 20:05:38.181 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[5] = "441154800.000000"
2015-05-15 20:05:38.182 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2015-05-15 20:05:38.186 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2015-05-15 20:05:38.187 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2015-05-15 20:05:38.187 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
2015-05-15 20:05:38.187 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2015-05-15 20:05:38.188 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 
2015-05-15 20:05:38.188 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
2015-05-15 20:05:38.190 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x78629ba0> on entity 'Setting' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 ' returned 1 rows with values: (
"<NSManagedObject: 0x786da760> (entity: Setting; id: 0x7862a570 <x-coredata://26333CDC-2708-470E-A0DE-F579A2BBCAC7/Setting/p1> ; data: {\n    dayOfExpiredDay = nil;\n    dayOfExpiredDay1 = 0;\n    timeOfExpiredDay = \"2014-12-24 23:00:00 +0000\";\n})")
2015-05-15 20:05:38.190 JPList[10577:646588] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0022s for 1 rows.
mySettingItem:<NSManagedObject: 0x786da760> (entity: Setting; id: 0x7862a570 <x-coredata://26333CDC-2708-470E-A0DE-F579A2BBCAC7/Setting/p1> ; data: {
    dayOfExpiredDay = nil;
    dayOfExpiredDay1 = 0;
    timeOfExpiredDay = "2014-12-24 23:00:00 +0000";
    })
```

***The second run the app and set the below output.***

```
2015-05-15 20:06:10.938 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE8973DD-5E27-4AA9-8976-1CBB39ED4F32/data/Containers/Data/Application/4305F6AF-EDA9-4301-8C10-578037E85FCE/Documents/JPList.sqlite"
2015-05-15 20:06:10.941 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: SELECT TBL_NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TBL_NAME = 'Z_METADATA'
2015-05-15 20:06:10.945 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
2015-05-15 20:06:10.945 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200
2015-05-15 20:06:10.945 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
2015-05-15 20:06:10.946 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZEXPIREDON, t0.ZFIRSTALARMON, t0.ZINFO, t0.ZITEM, t0.ZPHOTO, t0.ZQUANTITY, t0.ZQUANTITY1 FROM ZLIST t0 
2015-05-15 20:06:10.946 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
2015-05-15 20:06:10.946 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x78e5ebd0> on entity 'List' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZEXPIREDON, t0.ZFIRSTALARMON, t0.ZINFO, t0.ZITEM, t0.ZPHOTO, t0.ZQUANTITY, t0.ZQUANTITY1 FROM ZLIST t0 ' returned 0 rows with values: ()
2015-05-15 20:06:10.946 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 0 rows.
2015-05-15 20:06:12.441 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 
2015-05-15 20:06:12.442 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
2015-05-15 20:06:12.442 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x78f865c0> on entity 'Setting' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY, t0.ZDAYOFEXPIREDDAY1, t0.ZTIMEOFEXPIREDDAY FROM ZSETTING t0 ' returned 1 rows with values: (
"<NSManagedObject: 0x78e78510> (entity: Setting; id: 0x7a260b20 <x-coredata://26333CDC-2708-470E-A0DE-F579A2BBCAC7/Setting/p1> ; data: <fault>)")
2015-05-15 20:06:12.442 JPList[10596:647402] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0011s for 1 rows.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `mySettingItem` that you fetch and log is not a hang over from a previous version of your code?  Does it work if you delete the app and rerun?

Comment: I have tried to run reset content and setting on Simulator and re-run again.  It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the class definition for `Setting`, and the definition for  `daysBeforeExpiredDate`?

Comment: The daysBeforeExpiredDate definition is var daysBeforeExpiredDate: Int!

Comment: Having a similar issue.